# Dockerfile with debian and Jar

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to run a Jar ( lets say helloworld.jar ) inside a docker container. The container should include debian as an OS . Whenever I start the container the Jar should run. Meaning it should run `java -jar helloworld.jar` on start. how can I do that ?

also , How can I make docker-compose.yml file from it
Thanks in advance

Comment: [This](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/) should be of use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN {add java install command here}
RUN mkdir /src
WORKDIR /src
ADD . .
CMD java helloworld.jar
```

Build an image using this via `docker build . -t helloworld` and run it `docker run helloworld`

Instead of using `ubuntu`, you could use available open jdk images.

Comment: btw, How can I make docker-compose.yml file from it

Comment: `docker-compose` helps in running containers. You would still need the dockerfile which has the instructions on what the image should contain.

Comment: A sample docker-compose could be:
```
helloworld:
 build: .
```


And then you could do `docker-compose build && docker-compose run helloworld`